# Run Scala REPL via Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, scala, command-prompt, read-eval-print-loop

For research reasons I want to be able to call the Scala REPL in my Java code. To do so I use Java's ProcessBuilder and call the command `scala`. Although the code nicely returns the welcome message of the scala REPL, the statements that I sent to it do not return any output or errors.

Note that my use of processbuilder is correct, I tested it on other commands and it works. It is specifically Scala that is not giving me any output or errors.

Why isn't Scala giving me any output? Is there a way to make it work?

Here is the short compilable version of my code:

```
public class CommandEvaluator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scala.bat");
        Process proc = pb.start();

        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERR");
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "OUT");

        // kick them off
        errorGobbler.start();
        outputGobbler.start();

        OutputStream outStream = proc.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(outStream);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while (true) { // REPL
            System.out.print("> ");
            String stat = br.readLine();
            pWriter.println(stat);
            pWriter.flush();
        }

    }

    private static class StreamGobbler extends Thread
    {
        private String type;
        private BufferedReader br;

        StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
        {
            this.type = type;

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```